# Transitioning basis line to linear line shortens/hide part of the line

Tags: javascript, d3.js, transition

I have done some work with d3.js but I'm stuck on this problem. I have a multi-line graph which starts with smooth lines and circles.

What I want to happen is when I toggle a legend button, the `line(s)` are supposed to transition between basis (smooth) and linear (normal). However, when I click the button I notice that the transition from basis to linear happens but then part of the line erases and doesn't match up with the points.

In order to create the lines I have two line functions. One for linear and one for basis.

```
  var lineGen = d3.svg.line()
  .interpolate("linear")
  .x(function(d) {
      return xScale(+d.tx_week);
    })
  .y(function(d) {
      return yScale(d.RelativeChange);
    });

  var lineMean = d3.svg.line()
  .interpolate("basis")
  .x(function(d) {
      return xScale(+d.week);
    })
  .y(function(d) {
      return yScale(d.amount);
    });
```

Then I create the basis line calling the `lineMean` function for the `d` attribute

```
  var line = tx_year_grp.selectAll("path")
  .data(function(d) { return [d]; })
  .enter().append("svg:path")
  .attr("class", "line")
  .attr("fill", "none")
  .attr("d", function(d) { return lineMean(d.values); })
  .style('stroke', function(d) {return color(d.key); })
  .on('mouseover', function(){
      var sel = d3.select(this)
      .style('stroke-width', 4)
      this.parentNode.parentNode.appendChild(this.parentNode);
    })
  .on('mouseout', function(d) {
      d3.select(this)
      .transition()
      .duration(750)
      .style('stroke-width', 2)
    });
```

Then I add transitions to all lines created.

```
  for(u=0; u < nested_data.length; u++){
    var pathId = document.getElementById('tx_year_grp' + nested_data[u].key);
    var updPath = d3.select(pathId).selectAll("path");
    var totalLength = updPath.node().getTotalLength();

    updPath
    .attr("stroke-dasharray", totalLength + " " + totalLength)
    .attr("stroke-dashoffset", totalLength)
    .transition()
    .duration(0)
    .ease("linear")
    .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0)

  }//end for
```

This does exactly what I want and creates a basis line. When I toggle my legend button to make the line linear and connect to the points, the transition occurs but then the line erases or overwrites itself so the line appears shorter and doesn't connect with all of the points.

Here is my code for changing the line. I call the `lineGen` function which switches the interpolation to 'linear'.

```
var linearLine = tx_year_grp.selectAll(".line");
             linearLine.transition()
              .duration(3000)
              .attr("d", function(d) { return lineGen(d.values); });
```

This seems fairly straightforward but I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Ok here's my interpretation:

The linear path will be longer than the basis path.

But it will still have the stroke dash-array you set to be the length of the basis path and then be blank for another equivalent length - `.attr("stroke-dasharray", totalLength + " " + totalLength)` (why do you have a stroke dash-array?). Therefore any portion of your linear line that's longer in path length than the basis line will be blank as it will extend into the empty bit of the stroke dash pattern. Try removing the stroke-dash property to see.

If this doesn't work, try making a jsfiddle so people can have a poke about

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion worked like a charm. I set the attribute "stroke-dasharray" to 0 and everything worked. I am using that attribute for animating my lines in transition (and it was in examples I was researching). Thanks again for your help!